# Extract only values betwen strings/ braces in bash

Tags: bash

Original text :

```
2013-08-29 08:51:24 777 IPMS 0123456 [Prce=101.078804, Size=1540000, even=15476.6]
```

Hi, can somone help me in extracing the below from the original text

```
2013-08-29 "08:51:24,777" IPMS 0123456 101.078804 1540000 15476.6
```

Comment: this is quite broad and your title does not match your description. Consider adding some more input together with the desired output. Also, what did you try so far?

Comment: original text is of space spererated and there are values inside [ ]. i want to extract only the values within [] (eg : 101.078804 1540000, etc] along with the other values. tried some awk and cut combinations like
awk -F '[, ]' '{print}' OzoneVolcker1_20150430.txt | cut -d= "[" -f1:f5 | cut -d= "]" -f1:f5

Comment: then [edit] your question providing this explanation together with more representative data

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
cat file.txt | tr '\[Prce=Siz,vn]' \ '            ' | awk -F" " '{$4="IPMS"; print}'
```

copy like that and give it a try.

Comment: yes, Sed did that trick. Thanks much for helping on this. Much appreciated Glenn & Andrew

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
sed 's/\(, \)\?[[:alpha:]]\+=/ /g; s/[][]//g' <<<"$text"
```

That removes words ending with `=`, optionally preceded by "comma space", then removes brackets.